# How can i attach an listener to listview?

Tags: android, listview, textview, listener

I have a `ListView` with a custom layout for each row having one `TextView` and three `EditText`. When I am clicking on individual row in `ListView` one activity is started and that takes you to another page.

I wrote some code but its not working. The code is shown below.

In adapter class getView() method i have place the below code

```
   convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.editcategorylist, null);
   convertView.setClickable(true); 
   convertView.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
```

and I declare the click listener in your ListActivity as follows

```
   lv=getListView();  
   myClickListener = new OnClickListener(){
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(CategoryList.this,AddSubCategoryList.class);
           startActivity(intent);    
       }
   };
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Use something like this

```
lv.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
{
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parentView, View childView, int position, long id) 
 {
    //Here write your code for starting the new activity on selection of list item
 }
 public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parentView) 
 {
 }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. i have already use above code but that not working. please tell me another way to do.

Comment: thats the tested way by me and many others however if that doesnt works for you I suggest you to post your whole code here to inspect

Comment: lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);getList();  lv.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this));lv=getListView();
lv.setClickable(true);lv.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parentView, View childView, int position, long id){
          Intent intent = new Intent(CategoryList.this,AddSubCategoryList.class);   startActivity(intent);    
        }public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parentView){}});}

Comment: ok try this

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
  {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
      {
    //wite your activity code here   
   }      
  });

Answer (score 3):

Please use [setOnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29)