# Android List Activity not working well

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Hello everyone, 
               I have a little problem regrading to list activity. I want to create a simple list of ( 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 ) and when I clicked on them a Toast will pop up and says clicked. But the application is not running. When I remove list (extends activity rather then ListActivity ) . The app just simply runs and shows a list. I want to apply OnlistItemClick. Hope you help. Here is xml and java code.

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   tools:context="com.annotationap.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp" >

</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

java code

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {




 private String[] array = {"1", "2" ,"3","4","5"};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView listView1;
    listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this,    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array );
    listView1.setAdapter(aa);

}


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

     Toast.makeText(this,"Clicked" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to implement an `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` in a normal `Activity`. In that case, here's a quick example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener, OnItemLongClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        list.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Long clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Problem solved. Can you guide me a bit on onItemLongClik. Want to do the same thing with that function. Thanks

Comment: Long click not working. Code it running quiet well. But longclick not working man.

Comment: @user3194062 Did you call `list.setOnItemLongClickListener(this)`?

Answer (score 1):

I think its not a big problem, you should search first before posting, 
just change your id of listView in XML file

> android:id="@android:id/list"

if you're going to use ListActivity then you must have to care about the listView's ID, you can change it but then you'll have to use simple Activity else than ListActivity.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting a listener for listView1. In onCreate you want to set something like this:

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
```

However are a few ways you can do this:

I always do the following:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Standard onCreate stuff

    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long arg3) {
                //this will run on click. 
            }
        });
```

[How can i attach an listener to listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560238/how-can-i-attach-an-listener-to-listview)

Info on listeners: 
http://martin.cubeactive.com/android-onclicklitener-tutorial/